# Ember.js - Can't use this.transitionTo

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, phonegap-plugins

I've combined Ember.js with Phonegap, here you see the Confirm API. But the problem is that I can't execute `this.transitionTo('index')` from this event driven function `onConfirm`..

Any Ideas ?

```
  App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        actions:{
            abort: function(){
                navigator.notification.confirm(
                    'Sind sie sicher ? ', 
                     onConfirm,            
                    'Abbrechen',          
                    ['NEIN','JA']     
                );
                function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
                    if (buttonIndex == 2){
                        this.transitionTo('index');
                    }                
                }

               //this.transitionTo('index');
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable scope. `this` is scoped to your `onConfirm` function, but you need it scoped to the outer context:

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
  if (buttonIndex == 2){
    this.transitionTo('index');
  }                
}.bind(this) // <-- scope "this" so you can transition
```

You can also do it like this, if you need legacy browser support:

```
var _self = this;
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
  if (buttonIndex == 2){
    _self.transitionTo('index');
  }                
}
```